# How to sort float values using QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a class that creates a table widget using QSortFilterProxyModel. The class will take a list of dictionaries as the data then fill table columns and rows with the key values of the dictionaries. When setting the table to sort by float values several of the fields from the table become invisible. However, when I sort the table by string values there are no issues. Do you have to specify types?

Sorting by float:  `self.proxyView.sortByColumn(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)`

[image]

Sorting by str: `self.proxyView.sortByColumn(2, Qt.AscendingOrder)`

[image]

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QDate, QDateTime, QRegExp, QSortFilterProxyModel, Qt,
        QTime, QModelIndex, QSize)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QIcon

class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name, data, columns=None, index=0, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)

        self.name = name

        #specify which keys of dictionary should be included in the table
        if columns:
            self.columns = columns      
        else:
            self.columns = data[0].keys()

        self.setData(data)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        '''
        Layout UI elements of table
        '''
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.model.setDynamicSortFilter(True)

        model = QStandardItemModel(0, len(self.columns), self)
        for i, column in enumerate(self.columns):
            model.setHeaderData(i, Qt.Horizontal, column)

        self.model.setSourceModel(model)

        self.proxyGroupBox = QGroupBox(self.name)

        self.proxyView = QTreeView()
        self.proxyView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.proxyView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.proxyView.setModel(self.model)
        self.proxyView.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.proxyView.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

        proxyLayout = QGridLayout()
        proxyLayout.addWidget(self.proxyView, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.proxyGroupBox.setLayout(proxyLayout)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.proxyGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.proxyView.sortByColumn(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.update(self.data)

        self.show()

    def setSourceModel(self, model):
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(model)

    def setData(self, data):
        self.data = [{k: x[k] for k in self.columns} for x in data]

    def setColumns(self, cols):
        self.columns = cols
        self.data = setData()

    def addRow(self, row_i, rowData):
        self.model.insertRow(row_i)

        for col_i, data in enumerate(rowData.values()):
           self.model.setData(self.model.index(row_i, col_i), data)

    def update(self, data):
        self.setData(data)
        self.model.removeRows(0, self.model.rowCount())

        for i, data in enumerate(self.data):
            self.addRow(i, data)

    def getRowIndex(self):
        try:
            return self.proxyView.selectedIndexes()[0].row()
        except:
            return False

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    data = [
        {'Lat': 1.123, 'Lon': 12.234, 'Desc': 'Point 1'},
        {'Lat': -2.123, 'Lon': 1.234, 'Desc': 'Point 2'},
        {'Lat': 3.123, 'Lon': -122.234, 'Desc': 'Point 3'},
        {'Lat': -22.123, 'Lon': -31.234, 'Desc': 'Point 4'},
        {'Lat': 33.123, 'Lon': -12.234, 'Desc': 'Point 5'}
    ]
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Table('Table', data)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

The problem is that you are adding the information in the proxymodel instead of the source model.

To better understand, let's use the following example: let's say the proxy orders it in ascending order respect to the first column, there is only 2 column and the following data is added: `[(2, 1), (1, 2), (-1, 0)]`:

- step 1:

```
2 x
```

- step 2:

```
2 1
```

- step 3:

```
2 1
1 x
```

- step 4:

```
1 x
2 2
```

- step 5:

```
 1 x
 2 2
-1 x
```

- step 6:

```
-1 x
 1 x
 2 0
```

When an item is added it is sorted, and by adding the next one it can be added in a wrong position by replacing a previous value and leaving an empty box.

### Solution:

To avoid this you must add this information to the source model since that is never rearranged.

```
class Table(QWidget):
    # ...
    def initUI(self):
        """
        Layout UI elements of table
        """
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxy_model.setDynamicSortFilter(True)

        self.source_model = QStandardItemModel(0, len(self.columns), self)
        for i, column in enumerate(self.columns):
            self.source_model.setHeaderData(i, Qt.Horizontal, column)

        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.source_model)

        self.proxyGroupBox = QGroupBox(self.name)

        self.proxyView = QTreeView()
        self.proxyView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.proxyView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.proxyView.setModel(self.proxy_model)
        self.proxyView.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.proxyView.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

        proxyLayout = QGridLayout()
        proxyLayout.addWidget(self.proxyView, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.proxyGroupBox.setLayout(proxyLayout)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.proxyGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.proxyView.sortByColumn(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.update(self.data)

        self.show()

    def setData(self, data):
        self.data = [{k: x[k] for k in self.columns} for x in data]


    def addRow(self, row_i, rowData):
        self.source_model.insertRow(row_i)

        for col_i, data in enumerate(rowData.values()):
            self.source_model.setData(self.source_model.index(row_i, col_i), data)

    def update(self, data):
        self.setData(data)
        self.source_model.removeRows(0, self.source_model.rowCount())

        for i, data in enumerate(self.data):
            self.addRow(i, data)

    # ...
```